# How to get calling method's name in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a parent class (or module) with methods that does something with the method name of child classes where the parent method is called. Example:

```
class Foo
  def foo
    puts __method__
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def bar
    foo
  end
end
```

When `Bar.new.bar` is called,it prints `:foo`, but I want to make it print `bar`.
How should `Foo#foo` method be to satisfy that behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Try [`caller`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/caller):

```
class Foo
  def foo
    puts caller[0][/`.*'/][1..-2]
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def bar
    foo
  end
end

Bar.new.bar #=> bar
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want! Thank you.

Comment: Alternatively `caller_locations.first.base_label`